# AppAuth oidc invalid State error when authenticating against identity server

Tags: android, ios, identityserver3, appauth

I've configured  an identity server 3 as an IdP for a project, we have 3 clients: MVC web, IOS and Android.
everything is good for MVC app, using Hybrid flow.

for IOS and Android, using the native oidc client ([AppAuth IOS](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS) and [AppAuth android](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android)) is not working, even though I configured the flow as Hybrid with PKCE.

now when I try to make a POC on android using Xamarin, and using IdentityModel.oidcClient everything works as expected, getting access, refresh and id tokens.
when using the AppAuth for IOS and android I am getting the following error:

```
{"type":0,"code":9,"errorDescription":"Response state param did not match request state"}
```

any idea what is missing ?

I am suspecting that those two native oidc clients aren't asking for shared secret of the clients, so the flow is corrupted because of that.

Comment: this is because the authorization response is returned as fragment on the redirect uri, while the oidc libraries is expecting a query string as a response, with that, the libraries are not succeeding in getting the response.
the libraries are not following specs, actually I am doubting that both libraries support Hybrid flow anyway.
they library are handling google IdP case, and that's it for the implementer.

Comment: The libraries are not Google specific; they implement the recommendations of OAuth2 for native apps: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-native-apps-07

Answer (score 1):

The data should be the same in the mobile app and in the Identity Server,

On The Server :

```
new Client
        {
            ClientId = "myClientId",
            ClientName = "myClientName",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.CodeAndClientCredentials,
            RequireConsent = false,

            ClientSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("myClientSecret".Sha256())
            },

            RedirectUris = { "myRedirectUri://callback" },

            AllowedScopes =
            {
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Phone,
            },

            AllowOfflineAccess = true
        }
```

On click login in android :

```
    AuthManager authManager = AuthManager.getInstance(this);
    AuthorizationService authService = authManager.getAuthService();
    Auth auth = authManager.getAuth();

    AuthorizationRequest authRequest = new AuthorizationRequest
        .Builder(
        authManager.getAuthConfig(),
        auth.getClientId(),
        auth.getResponseType(),
        Uri.parse(auth.getRedirectUri()))
        .setScope(auth.getScope())
        .build();

    Intent authIntent = new Intent(this, LoginAuthActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, authRequest.hashCode(), authIntent, 0);

    authService.performAuthorizationRequest(
        authRequest,
        pendingIntent);
```

Ask for the token :

```
    final AuthorizationResponse resp = AuthorizationResponse.fromIntent(getIntent());
    AuthorizationException ex = AuthorizationException.fromIntent(getIntent());

    final AuthManager authManager = AuthManager.getInstance(this);
    authManager.setAuthState(resp,ex);

    if (resp != null) {

        ClientSecretPost clientSecretPost = new ClientSecretPost(authManager.getAuth().getClientSecret());
        TokenRequest tokenRequest = new TokenRequest
            .Builder(authManager.getAuthConfig(), authManager.getAuth().getClientId())
            .setAuthorizationCode(resp.authorizationCode)
            .setRedirectUri(Uri.parse(authManager.getAuth().getRedirectUri()))
            .build();

        mAuthService = authManager.getAuthService();

        mAuthService.performTokenRequest(tokenRequest, clientSecretPost, new AuthorizationService.TokenResponseCallback() {
            @Override public void onTokenRequestCompleted(@Nullable TokenResponse response, @Nullable AuthorizationException ex) {
                if(ex == null) {
                    authManager.updateAuthState(response,ex);
                    MyApp.Token = authManager.getAuthState().getIdToken();
                    startService(new Intent(LoginAuthActivity.this, TokenService.class));
                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoginAuthActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(mainIntent);
                    finish();
                }
                else{
                    Intent loginIntent = new Intent(LoginAuthActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(loginIntent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });

        // authorization completed
    } else {
        // authorization failed, check ex for more details
        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(LoginAuthActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
        finish();
    }
```

The AuthManager Class :

```
public class AuthManager {
private static AuthManager instance;
private AuthState mAuthState;
private Auth mAuth;
private AuthorizationServiceConfiguration mAuthConfig;
private SharedPreferencesRepository mSharedPrefRep;
private AuthorizationService mAuthService;

public static AuthManager getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new AuthManager(context);
    }
    return instance;
}

private AuthManager(Context context){
    mSharedPrefRep = new SharedPreferencesRepository(context);
    setAuthData();
    mAuthConfig = new AuthorizationServiceConfiguration(
            Uri.parse(mAuth.getAuthorizationEndpointUri()),
            Uri.parse(mAuth.getTokenEndpointUri()),
            null);
    mAuthState = mSharedPrefRep.getAuthState();

    mAuthService = new AuthorizationService(context);
}



public AuthorizationServiceConfiguration getAuthConfig() {
    return mAuthConfig;
}

public Auth getAuth() {
    if(mAuth == null){
       setAuthData();
    }

    return mAuth;
}

public AuthState getAuthState(){
    return mAuthState;
}

public void updateAuthState(TokenResponse response, AuthorizationException ex){
    mAuthState.update(response,ex);
    mSharedPrefRep.saveAuthState(mAuthState);
}

public void setAuthState(AuthorizationResponse response, AuthorizationException ex){
    if(mAuthState == null)
        mAuthState = new AuthState(response,ex);

    mSharedPrefRep.saveAuthState(mAuthState);
}

public AuthorizationService getAuthService(){
    return mAuthService;
}

private void setAuthData(){
    mAuth = new Auth();
    mAuth.setClientId(BuildConfig.CLIENT_ID);
    mAuth.setAuthorizationEndpointUri(BuildConfig.AUTHORIZSTION_END_POINT_URI);
    mAuth.setClientSecret(BuildConfig.CLIENT_SECRET);
    mAuth.setRedirectUri(BuildConfig.REDIRECT_URI);
    mAuth.setScope(BuildConfig.SCOPE);
    mAuth.setTokenEndpointUri(BuildConfig.TOKEN_END_POINT_URI);
    mAuth.setResponseType(BuildConfig.RESPONSE_TYPE);
}
}
```

The Service here will ask for the refresh token.

I have made a sample using Identity Server 4 with AppAuth-Android you can check it [here](https://github.com/hadiidbouk/AppAuthIdentityServer4)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16649743)

Comment: I Edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

We have an open issue for hybrid flow support on AppAuth-Android [here](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android/issues/75). The main issue with this is that the hybrid flow is a poor fit for mobile applications, as it would require repeatedly triggering a web flow via SafariViewController / CustomTab every time the access token expires. Acquiring a refresh token to allow background update of access tokens is better for native apps.

As IdentityServer3 is a certified OpenID Connect implementation, you should be able to use the authorization code flow to obtain a refresh token.